# How to map and flatmap a composition of cats free monad and ZIO

Tags: scala, scala-cats, monad-transformers, zio, free-monad

guys.
I am currently trying to build a ZIO based application.

Question:

Is there any way to map and flatmap a composition of cats free monad and ZIO like the example below?

```scala
// Suppose we have a free monad like this
sealed trait SomeFMA[A]
type SomeFM[A] = Free[SomeFMA, A]

// and methods like these
def fnA: URIO[Has[D], SomeFM[Int]] = ???
def fnB: URIO[Has[E], SomeFM[Int]] = ???

// This is what I'd like to achieve
def program: URIO[Has[D] with Has[E], SomeFM[Int]] = for {
  a <- fnA
  b <- fnB
} yield a + b
```

What I have tried:

I know the example above does not work. You have to have a monad transformer to extract a value from a composed monad. So, I tried to use FreeT to make it possible.

```scala
type SomeFMT[M[_], A] = FreeT[SomeFMA, M, A]

def fnA: SomeFMT[URIO[Has[D], *], Int] = ???
def fnB: SomeFMT[URIO[Has[E], *], Int] = ???

// Main program (throws a type mismatch error)
def program: SomeFMT[URIO[Has[D] with Has[E], *], Int] = for {
  a <- fnA
  b <- fnB
} yield a + b
```

The example above throws a compilation error saying type mismatch. The dependency types are not merged in the ZIO environment type parameter.

```scala
SomeFMT[URIO[Has[D] with Has[E], *], Int] // expected return type
SomeFMT[URIO[Has[E], *], Int] // actual return type
```

I am completely stuck at this point. I really appreciate if you guys could help me with this!

Comment: Can you avoid the mix in the first place?

Comment: Actually I can avoid it by evaluating the free monad's effect first and wrapping the result with ZIO. But I wanna avoid nested for statement, which is one of the reason why I am trying to tackle this problem. (and I'm just curious if there's any way to solve this.)